# How does the '->' operator work and is it a good implementation to modify a large string?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to begin with saying that I have worked with pointers before and I assumed I understood how they worked. As in,

```
int x = 5;
int *y = &x;
*y = 3;
std::cout << x; // Would output 3
```

But then I wanted to make a method which modifies a rather large string and I believe therefore it would be better to pass a reference to the string in order to avoid passing the entire string back and fourth. So I pass my string to `myFunc()` and I do the same thing as I did with the numbers above. Which means I can modify `*str` as I do in the code below. But in order to use methods for `String` I need to use the `->` operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int myFunc(std::string *str) { // Retrieve the address to which str will point to.

    *str = "String from myFunc"; // This is how I would normally change the value of myString
    str->replace(0, 1, "s"); // Replacing index 0 with a lowercase s.
    return 0; 
}


int main() {

    std::string myString << "String from main";
    myFunc(&myString); // Pass address of myString to myFunc()

}
```

**My questions are:**

- Since `str` in myFunc is an address, why can an address use an
  operator such as `->` and how does it work? Is it as simple as the
  object at the address `str`'s method is used? `str->replace(); // str->myString.replace()?`
- Is this a good implementation of modifying a large string or would it better to pass the string to the method and return the string when its modified??

Comment: 1) `->` will do 2 things: dereference the pointer and then access and call `replace()` 2) I would go with pass by reference (however eventually its the same as pass by pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` is a pointer to `std::string` object. The arrow operator, `->`, is used to dereference the pointer and then access its member. Alternatively, you can also write `(*str).replace(0,1,"s")`; here, `*` dereferences the pointer and then `.` access the member function `replace()`.

Pointers are often confusing; it is better to use references when possible.

```
void myFunc(std::string &str) { // Retrieve the address to which str will point to.

    str = "String from myFunc"; // This is how I would normally change the value of myString
    str.replace(0, 1, "s"); // Replacing index 0 with a lowercase s. 
}

int main() {

    std::string myString = "String from main";
    myFunc(myString); // Pass address of myString to myFunc()

}
```

> Is this a good implementation of modifying a large string or would it better to pass the string to the method and return the string when its modified??

If you don't want to change the original string then create a new string and return it.

If it's ok for your application to modify the original string then do it. Also you can return a reference to a modified string if you need to chain function calls.

```
std::string& myFunc(std::string &str) { // Retrieve the address to which str will point to.

    str = "String from myFunc"; // This is how I would normally change the value of myString

    return str.replace(0, 1, "s"); // Replacing index 0 with a lowercase s.
    
}
```

Comment: So when you pass by reference do you retrieve the address in `myFunc(std::string &str)` even if you pass `myString` when you call it? Does this mean that `&str == &myString // equals true?`

Comment: references are better understood as aliases. I guess your confusion arises from operator `&`. When its used at time of declaration like `int &i = a;` it's declaring an alias for original variable.(Note references must be initialized at the time of declaration and they cant be reassigned to.) on the other hand `&a` is used after you have already declared variable `a` and want to retrieve its address thats why it's also called `addressof` operator. `&str` is not same as `&myString`

Comment: When would I ever use `int &i = a;` if its not the same?

Comment: @darclander It was just an example to show the syntax. You'll mostly use reference variables as parameter. If the parameter is modified it'll actually affect value of argument (value passed to function). Please have a look at  [faqs about references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references)

Answer (score 2):

`ptr->x` is identical to `(*ptr).x` unless `->` is overridden for a type you're dereferencing. On normal pointers, that works as you'd expect it to.

As for implementation, profile it when you implement it. You can't know what compiler will do with this once you turn optimizations on. For example, if given function gets inlined, you won't even have any extra indirection in the first place and it won't matter which way you do it. As long as you don't allocate a new string, differences should generally be negligible.